# Angular2: How to add .map() to Observable API object?

Tags: angular

I want to add id to my API response (in client side). Im using something like that:

```
getMhpById(mhpId: number): Observable<MhpDto> {
    var result: Observable<MhpDto> = this.http.get<MhpDto>(
        `${this.apiBaseUrl}csbins/accounting/mhp/${mhpId}`);
    return result;
}
```

---

EDIT:

This is my Dto:

```
export class MbRiskDto {
  id: string;    //API RESPONSE DOES NOT HAVE THIS id FIELD.
  hesNo: number;
  finKod: string;
  risKod: number;
  unvan: string; 
}
```

And this is my API response:

```
[
  {
    "hesNo": "103001234567890",
    "finKod": "FD",
    "risKod": "123",
    "unvan": "TEST INC."
  },
  {
    "hesNo": "103000091287348",
    "finKod": "OD",
    "risKod": "ATS",
    "unvan": "FALCON INC."
  }
]
```

This service gets list from api and returns it as Dto. I also want to add id to my returning object. But there is no id field in my Api. I know that I'm gonna use .map() but can't find how to use it. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Can you clarify what is the problem you are facing? Some examples of data on the server side, what client side expects, etc. would be helpful.

Comment: show the data receive from api and what you want to display to client side.?

Comment: I've added details, please check this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working like below. Thank you for hints

```
getGlList2(): Observable<MbRiskDto[]> {
    var result: Observable<MbRiskDto[]> = this.http.get<MbRiskDto[]>(
        'restfull_link').do(x => x.map(i => i.id = _.uuid()));
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getMhpById(mhpId: number): Observable<MhpDto> {
    return this.http.get<MhpDto>(`${this.apiBaseUrl}csbins/accounting/mhp/${mhpId}`)
        .do(dto => dto.id = mhpId);
}
```

Comment: Please consider providing a brief explanation of your answer so it can be better understood how/why it solves the asker's problem.